# AS3: Collision Issues With Swipe and Pan Movement

Tags: actionscript-3, collision-detection

So I currently have walls all around the stage. With a square in the middle. The user is currently able to pan the square around the screen and swipe to move the square. The issue I am having is that when the user does pan the square does not stop at the wall it goes over it a little bit but does stop at a certain spot. But when the user does swipe actions it just keeps going and ignores the wall is even there.. So here is the code I am using.

```
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.events.TransformGestureEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.events.TouchEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.geom.Point;

stage.frameRate = 60;

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

var myshape:Shape;
myshape = new Shape();
myshape.graphics.lineStyle(8, Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
myshape.filters = [new BlurFilter()];

var friction:Number = .85;
square_mc.spd = 2;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, main);
square_mc.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN, onPan);
square_mc.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ROTATE, onRotate);
square_mc.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, onZoom);
stage.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE , onSwipe);
Square_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, addSquare);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, activateDraw);

MovieClip(root).square_mc.visible = false;

function main(e:Event):void{
    square_mc.prevX = square_mc.x;
    square_mc.prevY = square_mc.y;

    square_mc.vx *= friction;
    square_mc.vy *= friction;

    square_mc.x += square_mc.vx;
    square_mc.y += square_mc.vy;

    if(collision(square_mc.cp, level_mc)){
        square_mc.x = square_mc.prevX;
        square_mc.y = square_mc.prevY;
    }
}

function collision(_cp:Array, _obj:MovieClip):Boolean{
    for(var i:int = 0; i < _cp.length; i++){
        if(_obj.hitTestPoint(_cp[i].x, _cp[i].y, true)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function activateDraw(event:MouseEvent):void{
    myshape.graphics.moveTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    addChild(myshape);

    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);
}

function lineDraw(event:MouseEvent):void{
    myshape.graphics.lineTo(mouseX, mouseY);
    event.updateAfterEvent();
}

function stopDraw(event:MouseEvent):void{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, lineDraw);
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDraw);

    myshape.graphics.clear();
    myshape.graphics.lineStyle(8, Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
}

stopDraw(null);

function onPan (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    square_mc.y += e.offsetY;
    square_mc.x += e.offsetX;
    square_mc.gotoAndStop(3);
}

function onRotate (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    square_mc.rotation += e.rotation;
    square_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
}

function onZoom (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    square_mc.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
    square_mc.scaleY *= e.scaleY;
    square_mc.gotoAndStop(4);
}


function onSwipe (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    if (e.offsetX == 1) { 
        //User swiped towards right
        square_mc.x += 100; 
    }
    if (e.offsetX == -1) { 
        //User swiped towards left
        square_mc.x -= 100;
    } 
    if (e.offsetY == 1) { 
        //User swiped towards bottom
        square_mc.y += 100; 
    }
    if (e.offsetY == -1) { 
        //User swiped towards top
        square_mc.y -= 100;
    } 
}

function addSquare (e:MouseEvent):void{
    if(Square_btn.currentFrame <= 1){
        Square_btn.gotoAndStop(2);
        MovieClip(root).square_mc.visible = true;
    }else{
        Square_btn.gotoAndStop(1);
        square_mc.gotoAndStop(1);
        MovieClip(root).square_mc.visible = false;
}
}
```

Comment: I do have a class on the player, not sure if you guys will need to that too. If you do I will gladly post it.

Comment: Depending on how big your walls are, it's possible your square just "jumps" over the wall at once. Especially with +100 like you do. What happens if you put swiping at +10? Does it work then?

Comment: Yeah even at ten it still goes over the walls